# ExtJS 4.2 Event Domain for Pub/Sub implementation

Tags: javascript, web-applications, extjs, publish-subscribe

In ExtJS 4.2, there's this new concept of *event domains*. It seems capable of being used as a pub/sub implementation rather than using third party codes such as ArbiterJS. It also allows more control over the scope of subscriptions allowed (controller, component, global, store).

Can anyone help list out what the advantages/disadvantages it has over other established pub/sub implementation for javascript?